# Font inconsolata unreadable under Windows 8.1 with small font sizes

Tags: windows, windows-8, fonts, eclipse

I always use inconsolata-g for programming but with font sizes under 11 it is unreadable in Windows 8.1. For example the equal sign is just displayed as a single line. I have clear type activated and if I deactivate it the characters are complete but very blurry.
How can I fix this?